# In Google Apps Script, is Range.getNextDataCell(...) supposed to fail when Range is hidden?

Tags: google-apps-script

In the Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service –

Where `tgt_range` is a `Range` object, the line `tgt_range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)` generates an "Exception: Invalid argument" if the group in the sheet within which `tgt_range` is contained is collapsed. However, the line runs without exception if the group is expanded.

I cannot find any documentation indicating that a range must be visible/expanded in order for the `.getNextDataCell(...)` method to execute.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or whether the behavior is by design?

Comment: Create a issue in the issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is a bug.

Methods that use the data region (range expanded in the four cardinal [Directions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/direction)) (e.g. [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection), [getDataRegion()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDataRegion()) throw an error if the starting (top-left) cell of the Range is hidden.

The specific error, though, is different depending on the method. While `getNextDataCell` throws `Invalid argument`, `getDataRegion` causes the script to run for about 30-40 seconds before throwing `Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id {SPREADSHEET_ID}`.

As a workaround, unhide the top-left cell of the range before calling this method, and hide it again after that.

#### Related bugs:

- [getNextDataCell throws Invalid argument when Range is hidden](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171281549)
- [getDataRegion failed when it faces hidden rows or columns](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146868763)